# modify multiple html files with Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I need to modify over a thousand html files in a certain directory. I need to remove all the content and replace it with the html below. What would be the best way of doing this?

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
Please use the Supplemental Information Browser to view approvad Servie  Bulletins
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is overwrite the contents of the files, just copy that HTML into a file in a different directory (for example, into `..\template.html`), and then execute

```
for %d in (*.html) do copy /Y ..\template.html %d
```

in the directory in which all of the files you need to overwrite are.

You don't even need Powershell to simply overwrite a group of files with exactly the same content.

Comment: yes it has already been corrected. fat finger and didn't spell check before I put it up