# Modify multiple html files in a directory folder with PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell

I want to insert some HTML code (8 lines) between code that already exist in 60 .html files. Some of the HTML files are in separate folders in the directory. I found this posting, but it only answers half of my issue.

[modify multiple html files with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989835/modify-multiple-html-files-with-powershell)

```html
<li><a href="/sites/abc/stores.aspx">Directed Stores</a></li>

**I want new code inserted here for 70 files in a directory by using PowerShell**

<li><a href="/sites/abc/stores.aspx">Non-directed Stores</a></li>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what code you've tried and which half of your question the linked question's answers successfully answered, so that answerers don't have to re-answer that half.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what step you're looking for help with. Do you know how to edit **one** file? Do you know how to run a command on multiple files?

Comment: There are countless ways to  "insert into the middle of a file". I'm not clear if you're asking for help with that part of the question, and I would need more information about the structure of these files to give useful/concrete advice about how I would opt to approach that problem. (For example, maybe you could just insert onto a specific line number?!)